# BigQuery: include procedures when copying a dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to copy a BigQuery dataset from one project to another. However, when I follow the documentation
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#required_permissions

I am only able to transfer the tables and not the procedures that are also stored in the same dataset. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: there is currently a feature request for this - you can follow it at [Allow copy stored procedures across datasets](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150780188)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to further contribute to the community I am posting @MikhalBerlyant`s answer as Community Wiki.

Currently there is an open Feature request for copying procedures between datasets. Although, there is no ETA for evaluation and implementation, you can follow any updates by following this thread, [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150780188).